# Alien girl lived in a hangar

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

Since I haven't found it for years, it's clear I'm not able to describe it as vividly as I could before. I only know a couple things about this book, which is most likely my problem.

I know that the main character is an alien girl. She escapes from what I remember to be a plane hangar, one she's apparently been hidden away in for years. This is detailed in the first chapter of the book. I don't know the girl's name, but I sort of remember it starting with a "P." One thing that is very clear in my mind about this book is that it had fairly bad grammar when I read the first chapter. Some words were capitalized when they weren't supposed to be, periods were misplaced, details like that. I also distinctly remember it being written by a British author, but I'm not exactly sure what the name was.

I'd really like to try fully reading this book, because it did have a slightly compelling plot. It would be really nice to get help in finding it again. When I read the first chapter, the year was 2015, but the book was definitely written before that time. Please help me find it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "because it did have a slightly compelling plot" - do you remember any other details of the plot, other than the girl escaping from a hangar? Those might help spark some memories...

Comment: I remember the alien girl having been trapped in the hangar for several years, possibly her whole life. I can also recall that when she escapes, she finds herself barefoot in a forest, but again I'm not exactly sure about that @DanJ

Comment: Is the bad grammar dialog, or just the narrative text of the book?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I don't actually think there was much dialogue in the first chapter, but it likely only carries through in the narrative text.

Comment: Was this a physical or electronic book?

Comment: This was a physical book.